# Upgrading the Android SDK version

Tags: flutter, settings, upgrade

Android Studio -> System Settings -> SDK Android -> SDK Platforms Android 13.0(Tiramisu) Installed.
I'm trying to upgrade the Android SDK version to 33.

I am getting Warning error:

> The plugin flutter_email_sender requires Android SDK version 33.

Inside app/build.gradle file I have:
'''Dart
android {

```
**compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion **

        ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
        compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        
**minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion**
**targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion**
```

I change to:

**compileSdkVersion 33**

**targetSdkVersion 33**
'''
I save the file, compile the project and i get an error:

> Build file 'C:\Users\Admin\AndroidStudioProjects\rozdzielnia\android\build.gradle' line: 26*** What went wrong:
> A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
>
> A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not open proj generic class cache for build file 'C:...\android\app\build.gradle' (C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\7.4\scripts\54yso35ibf29r0rk62zlu1wmq).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 63**

I found the presented solution on the forum. However, I don't know what is causing the error and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to

> android/app/src/build.gradle

inside android class change it to 33

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 33 // <== Here's your compiled version
...
..
}
```

and inside android class there is another class called defaultConfig

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "your.app.bundle"
    minSdkVersion 21 // <== checkout y
    targetSdkVersion 33 // <== make sure this is 33
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```

and inside your AndroidManifest.xml

> android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

you must add these lines of code to support android 11

```
<queries>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
    <data android:scheme="mailto" />
   </intent>
 </queries>
```

Comment: Thank you. Additional entry in the manifest file has performed the update.

Comment: Does it work now? if yes please vote up :)